# Using VBA to query a VIEW from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA script that will pull the results from a View (`SELECT * FROM view_name`) from the `RecordSet.Source` property, but when attempted, my *CloseConnection* error handler keeps getting caught. I can get results from a table using a simple query like `SELECT * FROM tbl_name` with no issues.

Below is the code I am using. Note: my Const variable has the Provider and Database information removed.

I guess it really comes down to is it even possible to get results from a View like I would from a table?

```vb
Option Explicit

Const ConStrMSSQL As String = _
"Provider=provider_name;Database=database_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Sub test()

    Dim formConnect As ADODB.connection
    Dim formData As ADODB.recordSet
    Dim formField As ADODB.Field

    Set formConnect = New ADODB.connection
    Set formData = New ADODB.recordSet

    formConnect.ConnectionString = ConStrMSSQL

    formConnect.Open

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    With formData
        .ActiveConnection = formConnect
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM v_data_extract_658"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    On Error GoTo CloseRecordset


    Sheets("test").Range("A1").Select

    For Each formField In formData.Fields
        ActiveCell.Value = formField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next formField

    Sheets("test").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset formData

    On Error GoTo 0

    CloseRecordset:
        formData.Close

    CloseConnection:
        formConnect.Close


End Sub
```

This is the error message:

> run-time error 2147467259 (80004005): unknown token received from SQL Server

Comment: All things being equal, querying a view should look exactly like querying a table.   Comment out the error handler: what is the error message you get?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you get rid of those ON ERROR GOTOs. You need to know about errors. What you have is an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. Handle the error gracefully and tell the user something happened. Just closing the window is a horrible way to "handle" an error. Very frustrating as a user when the program just closes.

Comment: @SeanLange You make good points. Please note that those error handlers were not the final product; more just placeholders.

Comment: Yes this should work fine. Be sure however that you have access to all the objects referenced in the view. For Example, the view might reference a Linked Server resource that you don't have access to. I've seen for example queries in DEV built atop objects that sit in STAGE/TEST.

Comment: @TimWilliams This is the error message:
run-time error 2147467259 (80004005): unknown token received from SQL Server

Comment: Also, be explicit with the views schema and also its database. You can stick both in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @flaZer Sorry for my lack of complete understand of SQL, but if I am able to run queries, for example, the query I am trying to run in the VBA script, on the server and database, would what you are saying still give me access issues in the VBA script?

Comment: @TimWilliams Forgot to mention this as well, but when I click debug, the cursor goes to Open property in the RecordSet.

Comment: You need this just after writing your field names:  **Sheets("test").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset formData**

Comment: @flaZer I edited my original post above. Is that where you are saying it should go? Also, I get the error with the Open property in the RecordSet, so I don't get to that part of the script.

Comment: This is probably a driver/library compatibility issue.  What provider are you using?  And what MDAC/ADODB version?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Provider = SQLNCLI10 I am not sure how to answer what MDAC/ADODB version... I am using Microsoft ActiveX Objects 6.1 Library, if that answers that question.

Comment: At the end of my rope on this one... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65516/what-causes-unknown-token-received-from-sql-server

Comment: Try switching to the OleDb provider.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry for my lack of understanding, but where would I locate that information?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried using SQLOLEDB and I got an error message: 'Unspecified Error'

Answer (score 1):

I think the big issue here is that you haven't defined a Command Object.

I somewhat put this together "freehand" and for certain, didn't test it but it should get you to where you need to go.

```
Sub test()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:

    Dim formConnect As ADODB.Connection
    Set formConnect = New ADODB.Connection

    formConnect.ConnectionString = ConStrMSSQL

    Dim cmd   As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    formConnect.Open

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = formConnect
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM v_data_extract_658"
        .CommandTimeout = 30
    End With

    Dim formData   As ADODB.Recordset
    Set formData = New ADODB.Recordset

    formData.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    Sheets("test").Range("A1").Select

    Dim formField As ADODB.Field
    For Each formField In formData.Fields
        ActiveCell.value = formField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next formField

    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset formData

    On Error GoTo 0

Cleanup:
    If Not formData Is Nothing Then
        If formData.State <> adStateClosed Then formData.Close
        Set formData = Nothing
    End If

    If Not formConnect Is Nothing Then
        If formConnect.State <> adStateClosed Then formConnect.Close
        Set formConnect = Nothing
    End If

    Set cmd = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Description

    'Do whatever else is needed to respond to errors.

    Resume Cleanup

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a heads-up,I had to move 'formConnect.Open' under 'formConnect.ConnectionString = ConStrMSSQL' to get the connection started. 

I did receive an error at this line: 'formData.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly'
Error Message: Unknown token received from sql server

Comment: thx - I've updated my answer to reflect the change you made. I guess at this point I'd explicitly spell out a few of the columns you expect to retrieve, because maybe either a column name or the content of a column might be causing the grief.

Comment: To confirm, are you saying do this in the CommandText property and completely replace what I have there now?

Comment: Saying for this "SELECT * FROM v_data_extract_658", explicitly specify a few columns.  Pick one or two that you expect to be consistent, like a Primary Key column, or those that have a Foreign Key Constraint. Purpose is try and isolate specifically where the choke point is.  If you can get at least a few columns - or just one - to return, you'll have a better idea regards where to look for problems.

Comment: I tried the first couple columns and received this error: 'Operation is not allowed when the object is close'. This happens because the connection closes on this line 'If formConnect.State <> adStateClosed Then formConnect.Close' Any idea why that is being triggered?

Comment: again and apologies I haven't tested this thing, but move the CLOSE statement past the **CopyFromRecordset**. Answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped with it not quitting on me. I keep getting back to the error: 'Unknown token received from sql server'. Being that the intent behind this script was to allow the user to generate the data by a button click, I am thinking maybe the code generated from recording a macro may be the best option to get the results I need.

Comment: Which ActiveX Library are you using? I've recently deployed a solution to multiple users, using the following: **Microsoft ActiveX Objects 2.7 Library** - I would next see if I had better success with other Libraries. My solution returns SQL Views, and also kicks off a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I am using **Microsoft ActiveX Objects 6.1 Library**. I tried 2.7 and still received the same error message: 'Unknown token received from sql server'. Is you CommandText property equaling something simple like: 'SELECT * FROM my_view_name'?

Comment: No - excel file, which is defined as an ADD-IN, can call up to 10 views and push those views to 10 different sheets.  Each SQL view is explicitly defined to return a set amount of columns and along the way, many columns are renamed by the INLINE SQL. It's a fairly complex ADDIN, including reads and writes from the User Registry so that each time the ADDIN is called, user preferences are both Read and Saved.  I'm throwing this at you to express that with everything going on in the ADDIN, the above approach works like a charm. Oh yeah, I'm also passing parameters too.

Comment: At the end of my rope on this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65516/what-causes-unknown-token-received-from-sql-server

Comment: I will have to check with one of my DBAs to see what they think based on the feedback from that link. If worse comes to worst, I will still have the option to get the VBA code from recording a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel & VBA to fetch dta from SLQ Server is quite easy (not always, but these days).

```vb
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "NORTHWND" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

As an aside, you can try this as well (please change to suit your specific setup/configuration)...

```vb
Sub Working2()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set con = New Connection
strConn = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True"

con.Open strConn

'Put a country name in Cell E1
Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.MyOrders '" & ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text & "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Text & "'")

'The total count of records is returned to Cell A5
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close

End Sub
```

Please see the link below for more details.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Excel%20Data%20Export%20to%20SQL%20Server%20Test%20Code

Comment: I tried the first option you provided and received the error message via error handling: "[Microsoft][ODBC Server Driver]Query timeout expired" on this line of code: 'rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic'. I am not sure if this is the reason, but SQLStr is set to pull data from a View.